# Rails i18n: changing de.errors.format:"%{attribute} %{message}" has no effect

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, internationalization, format, formtastic

We use some self written validations for our applications. These dont use one of the already translated ones like 'empty' or 'invalid'. They are formated by the default way "%{attribute} %{message}"

However, our customers demand to format them in "%{attribute}**:** %{message}**.**", just some added punctuations.

These are the error messages in the customer i18n:

```
errors:  
  models: 
    foo:
      attributes:
        bar:
          steak_missing: sie haben Ihr Schnitzel vergessen
          beer_missing: sie haben Ihr Bier vergessen
```

Leading to ugly:

```
Bar sie haben Ihr Schnitzel vergessen
```

Since these can be chained, we need to have them like this:

```
Bar: sie haben Ihr Schnitzel vergessen, sie haben Ihr Bier vergessen.
```

Having this changed in the base i18n:

```
  errors: &errors
    format: ! "%{attribute}: %{message}."
```

Shows no effect at all. Neither does totally removing or anything else. We are using **formtastic** and its **semantic_errors** , does it provide its own i18n for (default) error messages?

Comment: Which Rails i18n backend are you using?  Also, do you have page, action or fragment caching turned on?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question - you use something like this in your forms:

```
<%= f.semantic_errors :bar %>
```

To change `semantic_errors` behaviour you can monkey-patch this method. To do this just add file `{RAILS_ROOT}/config/initializers/semantic_errors_patch.rb` with content:

```
Formtastic::Helpers::ErrorsHelper.class_eval do
  def semantic_errors(*args)
    html_options = args.extract_options!
    args = args - [:base]

    full_errors = args.inject([]) do |array, method|
      attribute = localized_string(method, method.to_sym, :label) || humanized_attribute_name(method)
      errors = Array(@object.errors[method.to_sym]).to_sentence
      errors.present? ? array << [attribute, errors].join(": ") : array ||= []
    end
    full_errors << @object.errors[:base]
    full_errors.flatten!
    full_errors.compact!

    return nil if full_errors.blank?

    html_options[:class] ||= "errors"
    template.content_tag(:ul, html_options) do
      Formtastic::Util.html_safe(full_errors.map { |error| template.content_tag(:li, Formtastic::Util.html_safe(error)) }.join)
    end
  end
end
```

This patch works well with `formtastic 2.2.1` and `rails 3.2.13`.

This patch will produce next string for two errors:

> Bar: sie haben Ihr Schnitzel vergessen und sie haben Ihr Bier vergessen.

If there is more errors it will produce something like:

> Amount: is not a number, can't be blank, and is too short (minimum is 2 characters)

You can chenge this behaviour on this line:

```
errors = Array(@object.errors[method.to_sym]).to_sentence
```

`@object.errors[method.to_sym]` - is collection of errors which produce final `errors` string.